# Copying char* values through Queues and threads on MBED OS

Tags: c, multithreading, arm, rtos, mbed

I am trying to implement some RTOS threads on Arm MBED OS over a K64F board. I am parting from the RTOS examples and I have succesfully run and communicated different threads using Queues. I am having problems when copying char* values from one struct to another to get a message from one queue to another. I believe I am misunderstanding something and that my problem is related to pointers and memory handling but I am not able to get through it.

I have defined diferent queues to send data to various threads. I have also created a basic data structure containing everything I need to go among these threads. In this struct I have a char* variable (rHostAddr) containing the remote host address that requested a service.

```
MemoryPool<cMsg, 16> AMPool;
Queue<cMsg, 16> AMQueue;
MemoryPool<cMsg, 16> ioLedPool;
Queue<cMsg, 16> ioLedQueue;

typedef struct{
    ...

    char* rHostAddr;
    ...
} cMsg;
```

In the Main Thread I am creating this data structure and putting it in the first queue (AMQueue).

```
--- Main Thread ---
cMsg *message = AMPool.alloc();

char* rcvaddrs = "111.111.111.111";
message->rHostAddr = "111.111.111.111";

rcvaddrs = (char*)addr.get_ip_address();
message->rHostAddr = rcvaddrs;

AMQueue.put(message);
```

On the Thread 1 I wait for a message to arrive and on certain conditions I copy the whole structure to a new one created from the corresponding pool and insert it on a new queue (ioLedQueue).

```
--- Thread 1 ---

cMsg *msg;
cMsg *ledm = ioLedPool.alloc();
osEvent evt = AMQueue.get();
msg = (cMsg*)evt.value.p;

msg.rHostAddr = ledm.rHostAddr;
printf("\t -- Host 1 -- %s\n\r", ledm->rHostAddr);
ioLedQueue.put(ledm);
```

On the Thread 2 I get the message structure and the data .

```
--- Thread 2 ---

cMsg *msg;
osEvent evt = ioLedQueue.get();
msg = (cMsg*)evt.value.p;
printf("\t -- Host 2  -- %s\n\r", msg->rHostAddr);
```

On this stage rHostAddr is empty. I can see the value on the printf "Host 1" but not in the "Host 2"

I believe (if I am not wrong) that the problem comes from assigning with = operand, as I am copying the address, not the value, and it is lost when first pool memory is freed. I have tried copying the value with memcpy, strcpy and even my own char by char but system hangs when calling this methods.

How can I copy the value through this queues?

Comment: Note that with `char *`, the value is a pointer and so the pointer will be copied. So now two structs point to the same string. Maybe you should copy the strings as well. You can do that by defining the `char *x` as e.g. `char x[123]`. Now the string data is part of the struct. Also, should the threads run on separate computers or have own memory, then the pointer passed from one to the other will be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I move it here as the correct answer was written as a comment. Converting the value to a array of chars was the way to go, so the string data is part of the struct.

```
char rHostAddr[40];
```

Now the assignation can be done with srtcpy method and it is passed through all the process correctly:

```
char* rcvaddrs = (char*)addr.get_ip_address();

strcpy(message->rHostAddr,rcvaddrs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this solution from ARM mbed:

https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-events